# Detecting a keyboard input in batch

Tags: batch-file

In a batch file im messing with, I want the program to `goto` a certain section after pressing a certain key, such as D. Is there any way to do this after pressing a key without also having to press enter? I'm sorta a beginner.

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html

Comment: Just as a note: it seems that you are referring to press a "keyboard _key_", such as "D". A "[button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Button_(computing)) input" is an entirely different thing and refer to an element on the screen. I suggest you to edit the question title and description and change "button" by "key".

Answer (score 4):

This is possible using the `choice` command. This command will wait for a keypress, and if the key is in the list of keys after `/c` then it returns the offset of the key pressed in the list of keys.

```
choice /c AB /m "Press A or B"
if errorlevel 2 goto optionb
if errorlevel 1 goto optiona
```

You can also use the optional `/n` arguement to hide the list of options (`[A,B]` in this case) that appears after the message text.

Comment: Wrong order of  `if errorlevel`  commands. `ERRORLEVEL number`  specifies a true condition if the last program run returned an exit code _equal to_ or **greater than** the number specified. You need to check `errorlevel` numbers in _descending sequence_.

Comment: Haha, I was actually typing a comment. I sent part of it by accident and saw you changes the answer.

Comment: Sorry. I wrote this answer at 3:00 in the morning so I missed a few things, but it should be fixed now.

Comment: That's fine. I went to bed right after I made this question. Is there anyway for it to register Spacebar, or at least, if I press anything but D it will goto another section?

Comment: You can listen to the `escape` key using `errorlevel 0`, but I don't believe there is a way to listen to the spacebar using `choice`. Apparently you can do this using [XCOPY](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=718), but I'm not sure that is useful to you. It seems a bit too complicated, and I'm not sure it's worth it.

Comment: @Blockerwiz read `choice /?` and try e.g. `choice /c A#B`. Then you get  `ERROR: Invalid choice. The valid choice characters are: a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and ASCII values of 128 to 254.`